# In $\Delta ABC,$ side $AC$ and the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ meet at $D$, where $BD$ bisects $\angle ABC$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

> In $\Delta ABC,$ side $AC$ and the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ meet at $D$, where $BD$ bisects $\angle ABC$. If $CD = 7$ and $[\Delta ABD] = a\sqrt{5}$ , find $a$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture:-

[image]

Let the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ pass through $BC$ at $E$ . 
Then I first noticed that $\Delta BDE \cong \Delta CDE$ from $(SAS)$ congruency. 
This gives the required information in the diagram, as well as we have $BD = 7$ . 
Now :- $$\Delta ABD \sim \Delta ACB$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{AD}{AB} = \frac{7}{BC} = \frac{AB}{AC}$$
So let $AD = k$ , $AB = m$ , $BE = EC = n$ . We have :-
$$\frac{k}{m} = \frac{7}{2n} = \frac{m}{(7+k)}$$

Comment: You are correct, there is not enough information to solve the problem without doing things in terms of $x$. You can see this by constructing an arbitrary $\triangle BCD$ such that $BD = CD = 7$. From there, you can use the angles you found to construct the rest of the triangle. This will work for any $\triangle BCD$. By the way, it's actually $2$ equations in $4$ variables because $a = b$ and $b = c$ implies $a = c$.

Comment: Ok, so what should I do next?

Comment: To find the area in terms of $x$, I would drop a perpendicular from $D$ to $AB$ (foot $F$). Then, $DE = DF$. You can use trigonometry to find $AD$, from which you can find $[ABD]$.

Comment: Why is $DE = DF$? Can you explain more, or I am missing something?

Comment: Because $\angle DBE = \angle DEF, \angle DEB = \angle DFB = 90^{\circ}$, and $DB = DB$ we have a SAA congruence between $\triangle DEB$ and $\triangle DFB$

Comment: What is $[\Delta ABD] $ area or perimeter?

Comment: The problem has no definite solution. Infinite different triangles like that can be built.

Comment: @Raffaele, $[\Delta ABD]$ is area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E=(0,0)$, $B=(-\alpha,0)$, $C=(\alpha,0)$, $D=(0,\beta)$. Then we have
$$\alpha^2+\beta^2=7^2=49,\quad\tan \angle ACB=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\in(0,\sqrt3).$$
Let $t=\tan \angle ACB$, then
$$y_{AB}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}(x+\alpha),\quad y_{AC}=-tx+\beta.$$
And we have
$$A=\left(-\alpha\frac{1+t^2}{3-t^2},\alpha\frac{4t}{3-t^2}\right),\quad |AB|=2\alpha\frac{1+t^2}{3-t^2}.$$
Thus, the area
\begin{align}
S_{\triangle ABD} &= \frac12|AB|\cdot|DE|\\
&=\alpha\beta\frac{1+t^2}{3-t^2}\\
&=\frac{49t}{3-t^2}\in(0,\infty).
\end{align}
If you have some other conditions such that $\frac{t}{3-t^2}=\sqrt5$, then $a=49$. If not, $a$ can be any positive real number.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**:- As others mentioned, this question was unsolvable before because there can be infinitely many such triangles. I also realized that is true because I missed a small detail that $AD = 9$. Sorry for the inconvenience. I also figured out how to solve this now.

I had figured out that :-
$$\frac{k}{m} = \frac{7}{2n} = \frac{m}{(7+k)}$$
With the new information this becomes :-
$$\frac{9}{m} = \frac{7}{2n} = \frac{m}{16}$$

From here, I get $m = 12$ , so I have the lengths of all the sides of $\Delta ABC$. 
Now from Heron's Formula I have :-
$$[\Delta ABD] = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
$$\rightarrow \sqrt{14 * 2 * 5 * 7}$$
$$\rightarrow \sqrt{980} = 14\sqrt{5}$$
So we have $a = 14$ as our solution.